# Is there a type used for numbers in C# that expands to fit its contents?

Tags: c#, math, memory, type-conversion

In C# the *string* type expands to hold as much data as you need to store (it has no set size).  Is there a type for numbers that accepts positive or negative numbers with or without decimals that works like this (no set size)?  If not how come?  It seems like I could avoid using long, int, short, byte, float, double and decimal if there was one type that could accommodate any number I put in.

Comment: use `BigInteger` it has no size limit

Comment: `the string type expands to fit it's contents`  Not so.  When you add to a string, a new one is created.  strings are immutable with a fixed size

Comment: in case of kind of *decimal* you have to set size: imagine, that you're given, say `1.0/3.0 == 0.333333...`. You have to set size to break the *infinite* sequence. Rational is not a remedy in *general case*: `e = 2.718281828459045...`. e.g. `BigDecimal` allowes to use up to `65536` digits

Comment: But why? theoretically a string could be infinite too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integers there is a `BigInteger` type in the System.Numerics assembly, but there is no such type for decimals.

Comment: There is not one built in, but someone did create a [BigDecimal nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BigDecimal/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no native numerical data type that will accept decimals in .NET that will auto-resize to fit its content. Not a bad idea though!

While a decimal won't resize to fit its contents, it will hold any number I have ever used for anything in any situation for the last 50 years:

+/-79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 with no decimal point; 
+/-7.9228162514264337593543950335 with 28 places to the right of the decimal; smallest non-zero number is 
+/-0.0000000000000000000000000001

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(v=vs.60).aspx)

If you just want to use ONE numerical data type, that is the one I would choose. But, there are speed and memory advantages to using the other types when they will work.

Comment: I understand I could use decimal for most numbers like you say but I was more interested in one type that would adjust its size to fit whatever number I give it.  i.e. if I give a decimal type a value of "1"  thats a huge waste

Comment: A wasted 13 Bytes isn't really so much in practical terms. Even for a million of them it would use less than 13 Megabytes.